# In which language is basically written Chrome Browser on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome

In which language is basically written Chrome Browser on Android?
Also, I read that JavaScript Engine V8 can be nested in every C++ application. How V8 is nested in Chrome? Also is there a difference between implementation V8 on Chrome under, for example, Linux system distribution and Android OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chrome and V8 are written in C++.](https://www.quora.com/What-programming-languages-are-web-browsers-like-Google-Chrome-Opera-and-Mozilla-Firefox-written-in)

While there is obviously some difference between the versions/projects (including Chrome vs Chromium) the language used and core code is the same.

A specific 'fork' - eg. ['Chrome Browser [for Android]'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en), or ['Chrome [for iOS]'](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrome-web-browser-by-google/id535886823?mt=8) - is compiled to the target platform with the appropriate build options. For example, V8 must JIT-compile differently for the different hardware it runs on; and the UI and feature-set is modified to suite the host as well.

However, [*Chrome does **not** use V8 on iOS*](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1312). Instead it uses JavaScriptCore. The same holds true for Firefox and is a result of much stricter Apple rules on dynamic native code execution.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on android and iOS both use a lightweight version chromium browser from the chromium project and yes it uses the v8 JavaScript interpreter. Though I don't think there is much difference in higher level implementation of V8 apart from the platform ones.

Comment: and yes the chrome for every platform is on its ground level based on chromium project. That is written in C++. chromium has alot of things in it. like the blink rendering engine, V8 JavaScript interpreter and what not..